# Microsoft Outlook - How to save entire Outlook folders to hard-drive and be able to search their emails content

Tags: microsoft-outlook, outlook-web-access

My company has decided to delete emails older than X-years to free some space.

**This includes ALL folders, including archive and my own folders.**

We use Microsoft Outlook Desktop in office and also OWA for viewing/responding to emails from any location in a browser.

I need to know how can I:

1. save entire folders such as my custom folders of emails to hard drive
2. and be able to efficiently search email bodies/content of the emails saved to hard-drive

Every solution/suggestion I have read about so far is talking about saving one-by-one email or emailing them all as attachment in one email.

**Imagine having to go through 10 years of emails and doing this.**  None of this makes sense as it is very inefficient.

Other issue is that some suggestions allow for searching email title only but not email bodies.

It is 21st century, it just does not make sense that there is no a better way.

**UPDATE**

This is what I see under C:/Users/me/AppData/Local/Microsoft/Outlook.  Hidden files and extensions are enabled, so nothing is hidden

[image]

Comment: Have you considered archiving your email. Archives are easy to load and search

Comment: Archives will also be deleted.  **ALL** folders with **ALL** emails older than x-years will be deleted including from archives

Comment: If you archive and move the archive it will be safe from deletion. i think

Comment: Have you consider export the old mails as CSV file and then import in Excel?

Comment: @romeoninov Your suggestion is a nonsense.  Emails are amenable to storing in CSV format and excel is not designed to handle that kind of data set.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/back-up-your-email-e5845b0b-1aeb-424f-924c-aa1c33b18833

Comment: @davidgo, this is the only other standard option to export mails from Outlook. I know this is not exactly mail format but OP will be able to keep mails and search

Comment: @davidgo, depend of how aggressive is applied this policy (to remove old mails) this file can be browsed too (and purged). And do not tell me to store it on flash drive, in enterprises usage of flash drives is very restrictive

Comment: @romeoninov why not just save them in PST format, or if the server supports IMAP use the IMAP protocol to back them all up?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144574/discussion-between-romeo-ninov-and-davidgo).

Comment: The question is about saving emails in folders such as inbox, my custom folders, etc to hard-drive and being able to search them efficiently.  Not about saving one-by-one email, not about company not allowing archive.  It is simply about not loosing important email due to a policy that does not want to keep any emails older than X years in any of Outlook folders.

Comment: PST's are collections of mail folders.  You should be able to copy whole folders into local accounts and simply back up their underlying PST's.

Answer (score 1):

Outlook saves backup information in a variety of different locations. Depending on what type of account you have, you can back up your emails, your personal address book, your navigation pane settings, your signatures, templates, and more.

If you're using a Microsoft Exchange, Microsoft 365, or Outlook.com account, your email messages are backed up on your email server. In most cases, you won't have a Personal Folders file (.pst) for these types of accounts.

If you have a POP or IMAP account, all of your information is already stored in a Personal Folders (.pst) file. You can move this file to a new computer and retain your information. Moving a .pst file from one computer to another doesn't transfer your email account settings. If you need to set up Outlook on a new computer, copy your .pst file from the old computer, then set up your email account on your new computer. You can then open the .pst file from the new computer.

The location of your .pst file depends on your version of Outlook, your version of Windows, and how you set up your account or created the .pst file. You can find your .pst file in one of the following locations:

Windows 10    drive:\Users<username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook

Windows 10    drive:\Users<username>\Roaming\Local\Microsoft\Outlook

Older versions of Windows    drive:\Documents and Settings<username>\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Outlook

Some of the folders might be hidden folders, and Windows might have file name extensions (such as .pst, .ost, .pab) turned off. To show hidden folders and file name extensions, do the following:

Open Control Panel.

In Windows 10, right-click the Start button, and then click Control Panel.

In Windows 8, press the Windows key + X, then click Control Panel.

In Windows 7, click Start > Control Panel.

In the View by list, make sure either Large icons or Small icons is selected so that you can see all the icons in Control Panel.

Click Folder Options.

Click the View tab.

In the Advanced settings box:

Under Files and Folders, uncheck the Hide extensions for known file types box

Under Hidden files and folders, click the Show hidden files, folders, and drives button.

Click OK.

Then you can use title or other sign to search for the mail you need.

Comment: Thank you.  I am using Microsoft Exchange (File > Info > Account Information shows that).  I dont see any .pst files at drive:\Users<username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook but I do see .nst and .ost files.  Please see **UPDATE** section I added in the post and thank you for your reply.  Is .ost file what I can copy on hard-drive and how to search its emails bodies for a string?

Comment: Yes,.ost file means Offline Outlook Data File.
**The offline Outlook Data File (.ost) is saved at drive:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook. Most data remains on the server; however, any items that are saved locally should be backed up. For example, Calendar, Contacts, Tasks, and any folders marked Local only.**

So you can use hard-drive as a local file storage location.

Comment: I dont really see anything being found.  I tried searching from Windows Explorer for a string in drive:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook where my .ost file is located.  Nothing is found.

Comment: Have you ever configured servers for outlook such as Exchange Server? If it is, maybe this case can give you some inspiration:[enter link description here][1]
The mailbox database has Microsoft's own storage rule.


  [1]: https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2478986-2010-exchange-large-user-mailbox?from_forum=33

Comment: No, this is enterprise, we dont have access to these things.

Comment: Sorry ,I will try to find another scheme as soon as possible and reply you as soon as possible.